Paste operation shows spinner for monaco editor in firefox
I am using Monaco Editor within a Salesforce LWC component as the code editor. All functionality works as expected, except for the paste operation, which shows a spinner whenever I try to paste content.
Below is a minimal code to reproduce the issue:
import { api, LightningElement } from 'lwc';
import { loadScript } from 'lightning/platformResourceLoader';
import MONACO_EDITOR from '@salesforce/resourceUrl/monacoEditor';

export default class MonacoEditor extends LightningElement {
    _editor;

    async renderedCallback() {
        if (this._editor) {
            return;
        }

        try {
            await loadScript(this, `${MONACO_EDITOR}/vs/loader.js`);
            window.require.config({ paths: { vs: `${MONACO_EDITOR}/vs` } });

            window.require(['vs/editor/editor.main'], () => {
                const container = this.refs.editor;
                this._editor = monaco.editor.create(container, {
                    value: this.expressionText,
                    theme: 'vs',
                    language: 'javascript',
                    automaticLayout: true,
                    minimap: { enabled: false },
                });
            });
        } catch (error) {
            console.error('Error loading Monaco Editor', error);
        }
    }
}

I do not see any exception, in the browser console. what could be triggering the spinner.?
Note: this behaviour only happens in firefox and works perfectly in chrome
